# How to use the output of select query as an input in the insert query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have following two tables:-

```
postgres=# select * from district;
 id |   name
----+-----------
  1 | Ahmedabad
  2 | Barmer
(2 rows)

postgres=# select * from warehouse;
 id | name | district_id
----+------+-------------
(0 rows)
```

I am referring district table from warehouse. 
Now I want to insert into warehouse. I am using following query

```
postgres=# insert into warehouse
(name, district_id)
values
('Ghodasar-WH', select id from district where name = 'Ahmedabad');
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 4: ('Ghodasar-WH', select id from district where name = 'Ahmeda...
```

But it gives me error, as shown above. Why I can't use the result of another select query in the insert query, as I am doing in above query ? 
I think, what I am doing is a valid scenario. Is there any limitations, that's preventing it from a valid case ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vao Tsun has the correct answer for using `insert . . . select` (and duly upvoted).

However, you are trying to use a subquery in `values()`.  That is allowed, but a subquery needs its own parentheses.  So your version would work as:

```
insert into warehouse (name, district_id)
    values ( 'Ghodasar-WH', (select id from district where name = 'Ahmedabad') );
```

Comment: I did not propose subquery, to avoid possible *more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression*, but now I think - maybe your way is better, so user sees that he has multiple rows, while mine will silently accept all returned rows

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
insert into warehouse
(name, district_id)
select 'Ghodasar-WH',id from district where name = 'Ahmedabad';
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

> { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) [, ...]
>   | query }

so just use `query` here